# toolStripComboBox set font style?

Tags: c#, .net, toolstrip

I read this topic http://technicalsol.blogspot.com/2009/03/combobox-set-font-style.html with comboBox but in toolstripComboBox not exist event draw_item
I need your help. I am writing simple wordpad by C#.

Comment: there is  DrawItem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem.aspx , if you are using WinForms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because ToolStripComboBox derives from ToolStripControlHost, not ComboBox.  You need to use its Control property to get to the combo box.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboBox box = (ComboBox)toolStripComboBox1.Control;
        box.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        box.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(box_MeasureItem);
        box.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(box_DrawItem);
    }

    void box_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
        // etc..
    }

    void box_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
        // etc..

    }
}
```

Fill in the event handlers with the code you need to measure and draw the font names in their own font style.