# Custom control in StatusStip control

Tags: .net, winforms, statusstrip

Is there a way to add a custom control to a `StatusStrip` Control?

Say, I need a multicolumn Combobox in the status bar...

Comment: Use ToolStripControlHost and the [ToolStripDesignerAvailability] attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the modest [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) mentioned, the solution was using the `ToolStripControlHost` and the `ToolStripDesignerAvailability` attribute.

More details could be consulted [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/10/05/477428.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to do the drawing yourself using a ToolStripComboBox and then place that control in your StatusStrip.  The ToolStripComboBox is different from the normal ComboBox because it [derives from the ToolStripControlHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155049/toolstripcombobox-set-font-style/5155458#5155458).

```
Dim comboStatus As New ToolStripComboBox
With DirectCast(comboStatus.Control, ComboBox)
  .DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
  AddHandler .DrawItem, AddressOf comboStatus_DrawItem
End With
StatusStrip1.Items.Add(comboStatus)
```

And then you use the DrawItem event:

```
Private Sub comboStatus_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)
  Dim comboStatus As ComboBox = sender
  e.DrawBackground()

  If e.Index > -1 Then
    //Do you drawing.
  End If
End Sub
```

See [ComboBox.DrawItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem.aspx) for the drawing details.

Comment: we use the Infragistics UltraCombo foe 2 columns comboboxes... So the problem is just to integrate the UltraCombo to the StatusStrip...